# Linux Partition full but it is really not

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, encryption, software-raid

I experienced a weird phenomenon right after the installation of Debian 9. It seems like my 2To /home partition (sdc1) is already full though I don't have much things in it yet

```
root@ripper:/home/david# df -h
Sys. de fichiers     Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
udev                    32G       0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  6,3G    9,9M  6,3G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1               57G    4,2G   50G   8% /
tmpfs                   32G     77M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5,0M    4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                   32G       0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdc1              2,3G    1,1G  1,2G  48% /home
tmpfs                  6,3G     12K  6,3G   1% /run/user/116
tmpfs                  6,3G     28K  6,3G   1% /run/user/1000
/home/david/.Private   2,3G    1,1G  1,2G  48% /home/david
```

df is wrong

```
root@ripper:/home/david# fdisk -l
Périphérique Amorçage Début        Fin   Secteurs Taille Id Type
/dev/sdc1              2048 3907028991 3907026944   1,8T 83 Linux
```

But, weirdly, I don't have much room either according to it.

```
root@ripper:/home/david# fdisk -s /dev/sdc1 
1953513472
```

At this point, I am not sure how to solve this (this is a bit to low level / hardware related for me).

Two relevant factors that *might* explain it:

- I encrypted my home using [this procedure](https://wiki.debian.org/TransparentEncryptionForHomeFolder)
- the disk was used in a software-RAID configuration before (weird look when I installed it)

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: which file system are you using? [This problem is often seen on btrfs](https://askubuntu.com/q/464074/253474)

Comment: a basic ext4, nothing original

Comment: your home partition is only 2.3GB, not 2TB, and it's only 48% used

Comment: Look at my fdisk command

Comment: Is it possible your sdc1 partition is 1.8TB, but the filesystem on it (that df sees) is only 2.3GB? Maybe it was created small or shrunk for some reason... if so you can try resizing the filesystem (or backup & reformat)

Answer (score 0):

Can you create files larger than the available space in that partition? What files do you currently have in your home and have you checked for any abnormally large ones (particularly that `.Private` folder?

You can try to create a file with the proper size (or a size that would fill most of the partition, but keep in mind that it will take a long time) and then properly delete it (example):

`dd bs=1M count=2000 if=/dev/urandom of=/home/david/tempfile`

This will create a 2G file filled with random data called `tempfile` located in your home directory.

And you can delete it with any tool like [shred](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shred) or [wipe](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wipe) for magnetic disks.

Other than that what you can try is to manually unmount your home partition, delete it, recreate, and encrypt it. EDIT: If you do try this last resort option, be sure to backup your data.

Comment: root@ripper:/home/david# dd bs=1G count=2 if=/dev/urandom of=/home/david/tempfile
dd: warning: partial read (33554431 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock
0+2 enregistrements lus
0+2 enregistrements écrits
67108862 bytes (67 MB, 64 MiB) copied, 1,14155 s, 58,8 MB/s

Comment: Try with a lower bs and higher count: `dd bs=1M count=2000 ....`. Edited my answer accordingly, as a lower bs is more practical. However, I'd suggest you go for something like `count=2000000` or at least 500000 to ensure that you create a large enough file to check for the space there is in your partition.

Comment: root@ripper:/home/david# dd bs=1M count=2 if=/dev/urandom of=/home/david/tempfile
2+0 enregistrements lus
2+0 enregistrements écrits
2097152 bytes (2,1 MB, 2,0 MiB) copied, 0,0361848 s, 58,0 MB/s

Comment: If bs is 1M, make the count in the thousands, not just 2.

Comment: to be honest with you, I don't even get what this command is trying to acheive

Answer (score 0):

When you encrypted `/home/david/.Private`, it created an encrypted container of **fixed size**, taking up 48% of your drive, according to your information. Whether you put 1 kB or 1 GB in that container, `/home/david/.Private` takes up 1.1 GB.

You can shrink the size of that encrypted container, which may require *un-encryption* and then *re-encryption*, or perhaps transferring the files first and then deleting that container.

Comment: Are you sure? `~/.Private` in that tutorial is encrypted via ecryptfs, and ecryptfs **does not work this way.** It doesn't have containers. It has the same space as its parent `/home` filesystem.

Comment: Do you have 1.2 GB of files inside it?

Comment: That's for the OP to know, but I wouldn't be surprised – it is after all the entire home directory.